# how to create a fixed footer with primary content visible and extra content hidden below, only visible after scroll to bottom with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how to create a footer with primary content always visible fixed bottom 
and extra content hidden below, only visible after scroll to bottom. 
using css.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer>
      primary content - this should be visible always (fixed) [copyright, logo etc.]
      ...
      extra content - initially hidden this should be visible only  when scrolled to bottom [extra links, careers link, policies link etc.]
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are going to need to show something you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSS/HTML only solution (no JavaScript), then you can use `position:sticky`. For this, you have to insert the paragraph that you want to always show in the bottom at the end of the `main` element:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
margin:0
}
#alwayshow{
position:sticky;
bottom:0;
display:block;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
padding:2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<main>
<div>
content goes here ...
</div>
<div id="alwayshow">primary content - this should be visible always (fixed) [copyright, logo etc.]</div>
</main>
<footer>
extra content - initially hidden this should be visible only  when scrolled to bottom [extra links, careers link, policies link etc.]
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Please be informed that sticky position is relatively new.